# wxmaxima: how to check a complex expression?

Tags: maxima

I wrote a complex expression in wxMaxima and I would like to see it printed in a pretty mathematical form, in order to check that there is no mistake in what I did.

Unfortunately the output received is already expanded and makes very difficult to double check.

Is there any way to prevent the automatic calculation in order to see what I introduced in a pretty mathematical form?

This is what I wrote:

```
δ:1/(Fz*E_al*Jx_al)*(integrate(Fz^2*s^2, s, 0, b-c)+integrate((Fz*s-Vc*(s-b+c))^2, s, b-c, b-f)
   +integrate((Fz*s-Vc*(s-b+c)-Ve*(s-b+f))^2, s, b-f, b))+
1/(Fz*E_fe*Jx_fe)*(integrate((Vc*s)^2,s,0,c)+integrate((Vc*s-Vb*(s-c))^2,s,c,c+a));
```

and this is what I got back:

```
((c*(Fz*b-(Fz*(b+a)*f)/(f+a))^2)/3+((c^3+3*Fz*a*c^2+3*Fz^2*a^2*c+(3*Fz^2-3*Fz+1)*a^3)*f^2+(((2-2*Fz)*a-2*Fz*b)*c^3+((-3*Fz^2-3*Fz)*a*b+(3*Fz-3*Fz^2)*a^2)*c^2-6*Fz^2*a^2*b*c+(Fz-3*Fz^2)*a^3*b+(3*Fz^2-5*Fz+2)*a^4)*f+(Fz^2*b^2+(2*Fz^2-2*Fz)*a*b+(Fz^2-2*Fz+1)*a^2)*c^3+(3*Fz^2*a*b^2+(3*Fz^2-3*Fz)*a^2*b)*c^2+3*Fz^2*a^2*b^2*c+Fz^2*a^3*b^2+(Fz-Fz^2)*a^4*b+(Fz^2-2*Fz+1)*a^5)/(3*f^2+6*a*f+3*a^2)-((c^3+3*Fz*a*c^2+3*Fz^2*a^2*c)*f^2+(((2-2*Fz)*a-2*Fz*b)*c^3+((-3*Fz^2-3*Fz)*a*b+(3*Fz-3*Fz^2)*a^2)*c^2-6*Fz^2*a^2*b*c)*f+(Fz^2*b^2+(2*Fz^2-2*Fz)*a*b+(Fz^2-2*Fz+1)*a^2)*c^3+(3*Fz^2*a*b^2+(3*Fz^2- [... ]
```

... and much more: impossible to double check :-(

Answer (score 0):

If you write `'integrate(...)` (with an unmatched single quote mark) instead of `integrate(...)`, the `integrate` function is not called, and the expression is displayed with an integral sign. In the example you showed, that would be

```
δ:1/(Fz*E_al*Jx_al)*('integrate(Fz^2*s^2, s, 0, b-c)+'integrate((Fz*s-Vc*(s-b+c))^2, s, b-c, b-f)
   +'integrate((Fz*s-Vc*(s-b+c)-Ve*(s-b+f))^2, s, b-f, b))+
1/(Fz*E_fe*Jx_fe)*('integrate((Vc*s)^2,s,0,c)+'integrate((Vc*s-Vb*(s-c))^2,s,c,c+a));
```

The unmatched single quote suppresses evaluation for other functions, e.g. if you wrote a function, `foo(x) := ...`, then `'foo(123)` suppresses the `foo` function call. In Maxima, an expression which has evaluation suppressed by unmatched single quote is called a noun expression.

When you want to evaluate the integrals or other noun expressions, you can say: `ev(δ, nouns);`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm new to Maxima but I'm sure I'm going to like it very much.